# Best way to handle includes when in a subdirectory?

Tags: html, css, apache, .htaccess

Sorry if this is at all unclear. Basically, I have created a small MVC framework in PHP. Everything works perfectly, but I've just tried to move the application into a subdirectory of the site's root, and it breaks everything. I expected this, as I've been referencing `/public/...` when referring to css/js files. The file structure looks like this:

```
/local/www/dev/ (web root)
    ref/
        application/
            controllers/
            views/
        config/
        system/
        public/
            js/
            css/
            index.php (handles all requests)
```

There are two `.htaccess` files. One in the `ref`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^$ public   [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

and one in `ref/public`

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$/? index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

 </IfModule>
```

When I go to `http://test.dev/ref/leads/5` the source is trying to find `/css/style.css` which worked previously, but not now it's in a subdirectory (obviously.) Is there anyway I can relatively include static files? Maybe using htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

The "`~`" should take you back to root. So try this:

`~/ref/public/css/style.css` when referring to your CSS file.

Comment: I don't believe that's what I need. I can reference the css by doing: `/ref/css/style.css` but this application is going to be in a bunch of different subdirectories and it'll be a pain to go through and prepend them all to anything that references the css. I was just wondering if there is a way maybe using htaccess to make all references to `/css/style.css` point to -> `/ref/css/style.css`

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry - I misunderstood the question.